# Doubts with Amazon workspaces and EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to rent/buy a server service in which I can run windows 7 with the following  purpose:  to install 4 programs. I need to work with them regularly but I cant install these programs from my PC, I have to be on the cloud server.

So my question, because the FAQ of each services do not state it clearly, if I rent workspace with windows 7 can I install any program I want? Can I do this as installation is done on a regular PC with windows 7 ??
I already tested the 4 programs I need to use on my windows 7 machine locally and they work perfectly. I only need to be sure they can work in Amazon web service as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS Workspaces does not actually run Windows 7, it runs  Windows Server 2008 R2, with a Windows 7 theme. (see "[What Operating System does a WorkSpace run?](https://aws.amazon.com/workspaces/faqs/#general)")

Due to Windows client licensing restrictions it is not possible to run an MS client OS in a cloud environment.

While  Windows Server 2008 R2 *should* run anything that Win7 can, there are a few apps that don't allow themselves to be run on a server OS.

Answer (score 2):

you can install softwares on your workspace, you are admin by default. But Workspace pricing is a monthly cost, so if you need only few usage of this machine you may want to consider using a windows ec2 instance instead

Comment: yes  was thinking to use windows ec2 instance, there also can I install anything I want ¿?

Comment: sure, if you create an ec2 instance it s very much as if you had a machine at home, except that it is hosted on the AWS cloud :) But it requires a bit more settings before you go (mainly network access and security groups)

Comment: thank you so much, I will use the windows ec2 instance.

Comment: @Tom How would I be able to view a ec2 instance in a virtual environment to lets say install Adobe After Effects? Is that possible?

Comment: if using a windows instance, use an RDP tool to have access to the desktop of your instance (there are plenty on google for free, e.g I use Microsoft Remote Desktop from my Mac when I have to work on windows)